# Undefined index errors after updates

Tags: scheduled-reminders, system-workflow-messages

We recently updated to the latest D7 version of CiviCRM and now we're getting a bunch of errors in the back-end logs. Scheduled reminders on events seem to not be going out, either. I've deleted the templates_c folder and let it recreate itself, cleared the cache, etc.

Here's what we're getting:

*Notice: Undefined index: defaultCurrencySymbol in include() (line 166 of /home/username/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%24/24E/24E27851%%jsortable.tpl.php).*

*Notice: Undefined index: participantListingURL in include() (line 54 of /home/username/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%58/580/5800D420%%Tab.tpl.php).*

*Notice: Undefined index: isAdmin in include() (line 15 of /home/username/public_html/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%14/140/14053CE4%%EmailCommon.tpl.php).*

Answer (score 0):

Undefined index notices don't affect the behavior of CiviCRM and you can ignore those.  That's not causing your Scheduled Reminders issue, which should be investigated separately.

A good [explanation of PHP notices is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4624505/2832108).  A common example is if you don't set a value on a variable, then try to do math on it, PHP will assume you meant the value to be zero - but it will emit a notice, since it's better to explicitly set a variable to zero.

The Smarty notices you're seeing is because of issue [core#1328](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1328).  In short, a design decision made in CiviCRM in the very early days leads to odd bugs, but fixing it causes notices in most Smarty templates unless someone changes them. This is more than can be done at once, so there are notices until the remaining notices are cleaned up.

Comment: Guess I've got to dig some more. The emails were sending, and then just stopped. And these were the only errors that come up in conjunction with it.

Comment: @JenniSimonis I can't speak to the email issue without knowing more info, but - a) make sure the Scheduled Job is firing, b) check the Scheduled Job log for Scheduled Reminders to make sure you see both the "job is starting" and "job finished successfully" notes, c) check the mail logs if you have access to them - I don't know where your logs are without knowing your Outbound Mail settings, but if you're using a third-party mailer like Sendgrid or Sparkpost, they usually have something called "Events" or "Logs" that shows individual email status.

Comment: Everything else seemed to be fine - nothing in the logs or anything. I created another one on the same event and it went out without problem. So not sure why the other one wasn't working since it was set up the exact same way.